# "Hopfenkaltschale" usual, unfamilar or frequent word for beer? What means "vegane Hopfenkaltschale"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Reading a tweet comes across this sentence

> Und es ist leider nicht die vegane Hopfenkaltschale, die viele Inder jetzt lieber im Rachen hätten

What does "vegane Hopfenkaltschale" mean in this context?

In what registers, contexts or regions and the word's frequency "Hopfenkaltschale" for beer?

Comment: Fun fact: McDonald's used to name their milkshakes *Happy McKaltschale* in Austria.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to Duden, [Kaltschale](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kaltschale) is a kind of soup that is served cold. "Hopfenkaltschale" could therefore be translated as "cold hops soup".

It is a name occasionally used to jokingly refer to beer.

There is even a Duden entry for [Hopfenkaltschale](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hopfenkaltschale), confirming this usage ("umgangssprachlich scherzhaft" - colloquial and jokingly) and frequency (low).

Whether beer is actually vegan depends on the applied definition of vegan (consider ingredients only or other components used in the production process, such as catalysts or filters) and the specifics of the production process (but such details are usually glossed over anyway when joking).

Comment: +1, Good answer although I would disagree with Duden's "low frequency": we use it quite often here exactly as described, jokingly. But this probably depends on region and personal preferences ;). You might want to add, that the addition "vegan" is a separate joke on everything being declared as "vegan" nowadays even for products where it is 100% obvious like apples or grapes and the word "vegan" does not add anything to the product description.

Comment: @TorstenLink well yes, I suppose the frequency of such jokes is unevenly distributed - it is certainly more popular with regular beer drinkers and less so with people preferring wine, for example. Even among beer drinkers, there are also other options like "Gerstensaft" or "isotonisches Erfrischungsgetränk auf Getreidebasis", but I felt that adding an explanation for the joke was not necessary - naming alcoholic drinks using healthy-sounding descriptions is an ancient trope.

Comment: never heard Hopfenkaltschale, but Hopfentee (regional, AT). which is strange as (hot) tea does not usually seem to be associated with (cold) beer...

Comment: @TorstenLink Well, apples are not really 100% vegan. To make them more shiny, sometimes wax or shellac are applied which are not vegan. Apart from that, I agree with you

Comment: Anecdote from CH: We like to order "Gerstensaft mit Vierkantrösti", which means beer and chips (french fries).

Comment: @dlatikay: In Germany we sometimes, in part, jokingly, recommend to drink a hot beer when someone is having a cold. Maybe Hopfentee is used in a similar context.

Comment: One might add that the word "Bier" does not sound posh, whereas "Hopfenkaltschale" does, so the joke is often applied in a situation where you want to play with the social status of the beverage.

Comment: @TorstenLink Like dlatikay I never heard "Hopfenkaltschale" before. I'm living in BaWü. Therefore I agree with "low frequency". I assume it's used frequently in communities where this word is established already, on the other side many people never have heard it.

Comment: I've come across *bean juice* used as a jokey way to refer to coffee in English, which is along similar lines.

Comment: @TorstenLink You might be right that it's used jokingly here but most beer is *not* vegan by the definition used by many (most, I think) vegans.

Answer (score 6):

"Hopfenkaltschale" is a used word for beer, as you have correctly recognized. And "vegane Hopfenkaltschale" is then just a vegan beer, although beer is already vegan anyway.

> Und es ist leider nicht das Bier, das die vielen Inder jetzt lieber im Rachen hätten

Comment: vegan in this context might mean *alcohol free*

Comment: Never heard, that a *vegan* beer means a *alcohol free* beer

Comment: In diesem Kontext halte ich ebenfalls eine *vegane Hopfenkaltschale* für *Flachbier*.

Comment: Beer *isn't necessarily* vegan or even vegetarian.  The finings/[Schönung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schönung) used to clear sediment may be derived from animal products (de.wikipedia, linked, has far more information than en.wikipedia though it's above my level; English wikpedia also has  and article on [the implications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarianism_and_beer))

Comment: Beer is *usually not vegan*.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Other people say differently: https://utopia.de/ratgeber/ist-bier-vegan-das-sollten-veganer-wissen/

Comment: @BernhardDöbler That's specific to German beer. In the UK (but I think also internationally), most beers uses isinglass or gelatine as fining.

Comment: Deutsches Bier ist normalerweise vegan. Soweit ich weiß ist das Reinheitsgebot eigentlich nicht mehr verpflichtend,  aber ich kenne keine deutsche Brauerei, die sich nicht daran hält. Im Ausland sieht es wohl anders aus.

Answer (score 4):

There is an aspect to this that has not been mentioned. "Hopfenkaltschale" or "Bierkaltschale" was a real dish. When you look at cooking books from the 19th century it is a common recipe.

From Dieter Gallun's. Aus Omas alten Kochbuch.

> BIERKALTSCHALE.
>
> 75 g geriebenes Brot
>
> 1 Stück Zitronen oder Apfelsinenschale
>
> 1 Prise gestoß. Zimt
>
> 65 g Zucker
>
> 1 Flasche Weißbier
>
> 65 g Korinthen
>
> Vorbereitung: Das Brot wird gerieben, die Korinthen werden
> aufgequollen.
>
> Zubereitung: Das Brot wird mit Gewürzen und Zucker gemischt, das Bier
> darauf gegossen; die aufgequollenen Korinthen werden dazu gegeben; das
> Ganze wird umgerührt und kalt gestellt.

Answer (score 3):

"Hopfenkaltschale" is a common joking reference to beer.  "Vegane Hopfenkaltschale" I have heard a lot less frequently, and as a reference to non-alcoholic beer.  While it does not make a lot of sense in the meaning of the word, it probably alludes to "real men" frowning on comestibles lacking in meat or alcohol.  So "vegan" is used in a "I am not permitted more than that in current circumstances" meaning.

In a similar vein, "vegan poker" would be playing poker but not for money.  It is a rather flexible invective.

Comment: Learned a new word there - had never heard "comestibles" before - thanks for that one (in addition to the insights on this use of "vegan" - I'm sure I'd understand it in context, but I haven't heard it used that way yet).

Comment: A while ago people said "bleifrei" (unleaded) in the same context. "Bleifreies Bier" is non-alcoholic.